# Choosing between single or dual buck LED driver ICs for LED driving

Tags: led, current, power-electronics, current-source, led-driver

I'm at a crossroads in designing an LED driving circuit and could use some insights. My setup involves driving LEDs in constant current mode, and I'm considering using a buck driver IC for this purpose. Here's the scenario:

I have 8 LEDs, divided equally across two independent boards (4 LEDs per board.)

Each LED has a forward voltage in the range of 2.8V to 3V.

The power supply voltage is 24V.

Given these parameters, I'm near the threshold where both boost and buck converters could be considered.

I am leaning towards a buck converter for efficiency reasons and simplicity in stepping down from 24V.

Here's my dilemma:

Would it be more advantageous to use a dual buck LED driver ICs with one channel for each board or could I use a single buck driver IC capable of delivering double the required current and wire the two LED strings in parallel?

Here is the idea of the buck converter with LEDs in parralel.

[image]

The circuit will measure the current on each branch to adjust the analog dimming value using a microcontroller and a DAC.

Comment: Dual. Two strings in parallel would still have a large chance that their forward voltages are too different.

Comment: Please show the circuit idea using a buck regulator just to make sure you have implemented current control correctly.

Comment: Yes, it's a good point, even if the difference should balance out on average. If we're looking for precision and repeatability in production, this argument is more than justifiable. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I would operate each series of 4 LEDs pulsed (increases efficency and AFAIR longevity) - similar to a buck converter, but not regulating output voltage, but the (low pass) filtered pulse current among a shunt resistor. Perhaps you can't use a buck converter IC therefore, if you cannot tweak the IC for the special usage for pulsed current mode. In pulsed current mode, the CLFT can be left away. Also because the forward voltage drops if the LED is heated up, this could lead to earlier failure/near/at overheating. The control loop has to be calculated well - if the LEDs are operated with pulses.